# Show that $\binom{n}{1}-3\binom{n}{3}+3^2\binom{n}{5}\cdots=0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, binomial-theorem

Show that if $n\equiv 0\pmod 6$ (although the statement holds true for $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$)

$\binom{n}{1}-3\binom{n}{3}+3^2\binom{n}{5}\cdots=0$

I am having trouble finding the appropriate polynomial to resolve this sum. Any hints? I prefer hints to complete solutions. I also have tried to come up with a probability story that gives me the relation above to no avail.

Comment: Consider the binomial expansion $(1 + x)^n$. I think you obtain the LHS using $x = \pm \sqrt{3}i$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I fixed it now

Comment: @sudeep5221 hmm, I had suspected going this route might be fruitful maybe that will work. I will check it out. You mean $(1+i\sqrt{3})^n-(1-i\sqrt{3})^n$ right?

Comment: Um.... what is the $...$ pattern and how long does it go for?

Comment: @fleablood When working with integers, it is convention to take $\binom{n}{k} =0$ when $k>n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By virtue of the binomial series, we have that
$$\binom{n}{1} - 3 \binom{n}{3} + 3^2 \binom{n}{5} + \ldots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{2k+1} (-3)^k = \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{3}} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right).$$
Since $n \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$, we have that $n=6k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Plug that in and you will have the result.

Comment: Does this result come from $(e^\frac{i\cdot\pi}{3}+1)^n$ and taking the imaginary part?

Comment: Oh wait, this is @sudeep5221's suggestion!

Comment: Yes, if you follow @sudeep5221's suggestion, you should obtain the RHS of the equality (unless I messed something up...). I just included the easy part :)

Comment: I think it's correct for the most part, but you should include more steps. Others might want to see the details. And I think the $2^n$ should be $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @crystal_math, $2^n$ is correct.

Comment: @RobPratt You're right, I forgot for a moment that the coefficients are also doubled.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $k$ is even}\\0&\text{if $k$ is odd}\end{cases}$$
we have $$\sum_{k\ge 0} a_{2k} = \sum_{k\ge 0} a_k \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}.$$
Now take $a_k=\binom{n}{k+1}(i\sqrt{3})^k$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{2k+1}(-3)^k &=\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{2k+1}(i\sqrt{3})^{2k} \\
&= \sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{k+1}(i\sqrt{3})^k \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{k+1}(i\sqrt{3})^k + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{k+1}(-i\sqrt{3})^k \\
&= \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{k+1}(i\sqrt{3})^{k+1} - \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{n}{k+1}(-i\sqrt{3})^{k+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k\ge 1} \binom{n}{k}(i\sqrt{3})^k - \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k\ge 1} \binom{n}{k}(-i\sqrt{3})^k \\
&= \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\left((1+i\sqrt{3})^n - 1\right) - \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\left((1-i\sqrt{3})^n-1\right) \\
&= \frac{(1+i\sqrt{3})^n-(1-i\sqrt{3})^n}{2i\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \frac{(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3))^n-(\cos(\pi/3)-i\sin(\pi/3))^n}{2i\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \frac{2^n(\cos(n\pi/3)+i\sin(n\pi/3))-2^n(\cos(n\pi/3)-i\sin(n\pi/3))}{2i\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \frac{2^n i\sin(n\pi/3)+2^n i\sin(n\pi/3)}{2i\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \frac{2^n\sin(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}